# Execute a c++ dll call only from a specific dot net assembly

Tags: c#, c++, .net, dll

I have an dotnet application from which i have to call a c++ dll. Now i wants to lock down the C++ dll so that ONLY that C# application can call it, and it wont work for anything else...ever. Is there a way to do that ?

I have an idea, but i'm not sure it is possible. I have code signing certificate, so that i can sign my application and pass my application handle to the dll and checks the certificate from the handle, which was signed by me, so that i call execute the dll or stop it and return.

Any suggestions please.

Comment: Let me see if I understand your question... You have a C++ dll that you need to use in your application, and that dll is going to perform some action that requires some kind of elevated privilege? My question is, what exactly are you "authorizing" ?

Comment: What do you mean by authorize? Do you need to run it with administrator privileges? If so, you cant just run your c# app with administrator privileges and the dll should inherit them.

Comment: My understanding is that he wants to lock down the C++ dll so that ONLY that C# application can call it, and it wont work for anything else...ever.  Can C++ get information on the Calling Assembly?  *goes off to browse msdn*

Answer (score 0):

This MSDN link will probably have what you are looking for, but I haven't attempted to use it in the way you are going to.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Reflection.Assembly%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

The Assembly class has such magnificent methods as `GetExecutingAssembly`, `GetCallingAssembly`, and `GetEntryAssembly`.  I would assume that doing something along the lines of `Assembly::GetExecutingAssembly()->GetCallingAssebmly()->FullName`...which may not be proper c++ code but you can probably see where I was going with that. (I specialize in C#, which would have a slightly different syntax there)

Comment: [This link](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/828736) on MSDN might be a starting-point for calling managed code (`GetExecutingAssembly()`) from your C++ code.